# Horas Exactas dadas 2 fechas en Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT a.*, 
     CAST(DATEDIFF (minute, a.fechaEntrada ,a.fechaSalida)/ 60.0 as decimal (18,2)) %24 as horasTrabajadas  
     from tblasistencia a 
     WHERE a.idClave = '" & empno & "' and a.fechaEntrada BETWEEN  '" & fechaInicio & "' AND '" & fechaFin & "' "
```

Cómo puedo mejorar la consulta, para que al hacer la suma de horas con la función `DATEDIFF` me devuelva más exacto los cálculos, es decir quiero hacer mas amigable para el usuario, la lectura de los datos.

```
Caso 1
21:00:50    06:02:51    9.03
```

Multiplicar 0.03 * 60 para que salga los 1.8 minutos a parte, es decir 9 hras y 1.8 minutos.

Resultado actual

```
 Hora A      Hora B     Suma
21:00:50    06:02:51    9.03
21:09:40    06:26:16    9.28
21:12:06    07:22:12    10.17
21:16:45    06:26:16    9.17
21:27:36    06:02:40    8.58
21:21:10    06:09:49    8.8
21:12:13    06:09:48    8.95
21:08:34    06:02:32    8.9
```

De la siguiente forma, salen las horas exactas pero no encuentro la forma de concatenar y agregarlas
a la consulta.

```
((DateDiff(Second, a.fechaEntrada, a.fechaSalida)%86400)/3600) + ':'+ 
(((DateDiff(Second,a.fechaEntrada, a.fechaSalida)%86400)%3600)/60)  horasTrabajadas
```

Comment: Esa ultima linea devuelve lo que vos queres? y a donde no lo podes agregar?

Comment: Si, no encuentro como agregarlo a Dim sql As String o también busco una mejor forma de hacerlo

Comment: Tu query ya tiene una columna con ese nombre, queres reemplazarla?

Comment: Parece que lo que buscas es retornar una cadena, deberías convertir los `datediff()` en `varchar`, algo así: `convert(varchar,((DateDiff(Second, a.fechaEntrada, a.fechaSalida)%86400)/3600) )+ ':'+  convert(varchar,(((DateDiff(Second,a.fechaEntrada, a.fechaSalida)%86400)%3600)/60)) horasTrabajadas`